# How to exclude history from go to definion and find symbol results

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have noticed VS Code adds matches from `.history` into go to definition and find symbol search results.

Say I search for method `AddSidebarItems`. As you can see it has only 6 matches.

[image: Search Accross all Files]

But when I use "find symbol" or choose "go to definition", a lot of incorrect results creep in.

[image: Find symbol]

[image: Go to definition]

Hovering over the result shows that it is from `.history`.

[image: Hovering over result]

I have added `.history` to `search.exclude` in my user settings but it does not seem to have affect here.

```
 "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/.history": true
    },
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/.history": true
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3260

Basically for now, you can use the `Clear Editor History` command (`cmd+shift+p` on mac) to clear the whole history. Or the `Remove from Editor History` command for individual items.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings (Ctrl+,), then add `**/.history` to the categories `files.exclude`, `search.exclude`, and `files.watcherExclude`.

In `settings.json`, it may look like this:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/.history": true
},
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/.history": true
},

// Add the following code to the setting configuration to exclude
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.history": true
}
```

Note that in more recent versions, some of the paths may be implicit, and therefore missing from the json file.